# Java api to search String in all tables of a DB and get matching results from all columns

Tags: java, mysql, database, search, full-text-search

I'm writing a java REST api where I need to search a String in all tables of MySQL DB and get all matching results from all columns of these tables . If there were only few columns I would have tried **full-text-search**.

Tried the following using full-text-search for 2 tables.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD FULLTEXT (column1,column2,column3, column4);
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD FULLTEXT (column5,column6);

select * from table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID 
WHERE (MATCH (column1,column2,column3, column4) AGAINST ('+test+val' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) or
MATCH(column5,column6) AGAINST ('+test+val' IN BOOLEAN MODE );
```

However there are more tables and lot of columns I can't proceed with this approach. Can anyone please let me know how to get the result set in efficient way.

Comment: How many tables are there ?

Comment: 6 tables and nearly 200 columns.